I'd like to change the legend, legend title and interactive tooltip in ggplot2, R

So here is the main data frame:

 Nr. x J' v'' J''      freq
1     1 0 77   0  76 13430.834
2     2 0 77   0  78 13413.756
3     3 0 77   1  76 13340.366
4     4 0 77   1  78 13323.356
5     5 0 77   2  76 13250.568
6     6 0 77   2  78 13233.628
7     7 0 77   3  76 13161.447
8     8 0 77   3  78 13144.578
9     9 0 77   4  76 13073.008
10   10 0 77   4  78 13056.210

Here is the secondary df:
J77_find
    Nr. x J' v'' J''      freq
1     1 0 77   0  76 13430.834
2     2 0 77   0  78 13413.756
3     3 0 77   1  76 13340.366
4     4 0 77   1  78 13323.356
5     5 0 77   2  76 13250.568
6     6 0 77   2  78 13233.628

Here is my code:
p <- ggplot(data = ajkr90_65_sp, aes(x = freq, y =int))+
 geom_line() +
 geom_point(data = J77_find, aes(x = freq, y = x, colour = "red"))+
 geom_text(data = J77_find, aes(label = v'',hjust=freq, vjust=0))
ggplotly(p)


Here is the graph:


The thing I'd like to improve on this graph is interactive tooltip.
Instead of frequency showing, I'd like to have the value that's in corresponding row in column "J''" in the secondary df, and instead of "x:0", I'd like to have the corresponding row value of the column "v''" in the secondary df.
I've got no idea as to how to solve this problem. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Welcome to SO.  ... aes(label = v'' ... appears to be a typo.  There are many examples of how to screate custom legends on SO.  See, for example, this.  Please ask about only a single problem in each question.
